# Structure of fragment isn't shown during design in android studio.Only the shade is shown.How to get the original fragment during design?

Tags: android, android-fragments

While designing the main activity I tried to add two fragments.But the original structure of the fragment is not shown in design tab of activity_main, instead shaded regions are shown for each fragment.How to get original structure of fragments during design?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgG9J.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

In your activity_main.xml make sure each of your fragment tags specify:

- `android:name` with a path to your fragment
- `tools:layout` with the fragment's layout

If you're using an include tag then you'll need to use something like `tools:showIn=".MainActivity"` ([docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#toolsshowin)) in your fragments.

Here's an example:

### *activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment android:name="com.example.FirstFragment"
        android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_first" />

    <fragment android:name="com.example.SecondFragment"
        android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second" />


</LinearLayout>
```

### *fragment_first.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```